# new folders from a list, from a text file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to create new folders from a list that is stored in a text file.
The names are stored like

```
test1  
test2  
test3
```

so my code so far, loads the path to create the new folders, (which is the oldest folder in the given parent folder) stored in another text file "Foldercreation.txt"

then open the file with the names of the folders I want to create, "Folderstocreate.txt" and stores them all in filereader2.

but then when trying to create the folders for each line nothing happens.

My current code;

```
Dim fileReader, filereader2 As System.IO.StreamReader
    Dim stringreader, parfolder As String
    Dim path, foldername As List(Of String)
    Dim count As Byte

  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to create these folders?, 

Before clicking yes, make sure EVERYONE is out of paperport & you have entered the correct numbers.", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "WARNING!") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            If strnumbx.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("You have not entered a start number for the folders.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
            End If

            'Loads a text file at the given location, to read to.
            fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("C:\Data\Test\Foldercreation.txt")
            'Set stringreader as the read line from the file
            stringreader = fileReader.ReadLine()

            path = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(stringreader).ToList
            path.Sort()
            count = path.Count - 1
            parfolder = path(count)

            'System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(parfolder & "\test")



            filereader2 = New StreamReader("C:\Data\Test\Folderstocreate.txt", True)

            filereader2.ReadToEnd()

            For Each line In filereader2.ReadToEnd()
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(parfolder & fileReader.ReadToEnd(count - 1))
                count = count + 1
            Next
        End If

        fileReader.Close()
        filereader2.Close()
```

Comment: you are using `ReadAllLine` but you said your values are separated by a white-space. which is it?

Comment: This site changed the formatting,they are on separate lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function would do it but you may want to put in some exception handling.

`Directory.CreateDirectory` will create all parent folders if they don't exist.

```
Private Sub CreateAllDirectories(ByVal strFileList As String)
    Dim strDirectories As String() = File.ReadAllLines(strFileList)

    For Each strDirectory As String In strDirectories
        If Not Directory.Exists(strDirectory) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strDirectory)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I suggested an edit since you were a bit faster to write the function couldn't bother to write it as well haha but i included a note about imports

Comment: Ya I thought about that note but was too lazy XD

Comment: A check for `If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strDirectory) Then...` would be prudent in case there's a blank line in there, as well as the exception handling you mention.

Comment: Thank you added the other variable and boom, worked perfectly